# I created my own logger in Java. Is it a bad idea?

Tags: java, logging, xpages, lotus-notes

I'm developing a web crawler using Java and XPages. I have had a lot of compatibility issues between log libraries like SLF4J, Log4J, java.util.logging, etc. and Lotus Notes.

So, I developed my own very simple logger class.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Calendar;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils;

public class Logger {
    private static final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    public enum Level {NONE, ERROR, WARNING, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE}

    private Level level = Level.NONE; 
    private PrintWriter stream = null;

    public void setLevel(Level l) {
        level = l;
    }

    public void setPrintWriter(PrintWriter f) {
        stream = f;
    }

    public void error(String m) {
        if (Level.ERROR.compareTo(level) <= 0) {
            format("ERROR", m);
        }
    }

    public void error(String m, Throwable e) {
        if (Level.ERROR.compareTo(level) <= 0) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
            sb.append(m);
            sb.append(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));

            format("ERROR", sb.toString());
        }
    }

    public void warn(String m) {
        if (Level.WARNING.compareTo(level) <= 0) {
            format("WARNING", m);
        }
    }

    public void warn(String m, Throwable e) {
        if (Level.WARNING.compareTo(level) <= 0) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
            sb.append(m);
            sb.append(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));

            format("WARNING", sb.toString());
        }
    }

    public void debug(String m) {
        if (Level.DEBUG.compareTo(level) <= 0) {
            format("DEBUG", m);
        }
    }

    public void info(String m) {
        if (Level.INFO.compareTo(level) <= 0) {
            format("INFO", m);
        }
    }

    public void trace(String m) {
        if (Level.TRACE.compareTo(level) <= 0) {
            format("TRACE", m);
        }
    }

    public void format(String type, String m) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
        sb.append("[");
        sb.append(type);
        sb.append("] ");
        sb.append(calendar.getTime().toString());
        sb.append(" - ");
        sb.append(m);

        String line = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(line);

        if (stream != null) {
            stream.println(line);
            stream.flush();
        } 
    }
}
```

My questions:

- Is it a bad idea to write a logger? Do I have to insist in make it works one of the existent log libraries?
- If I decide to use always this logger, what features I will miss from the log libraries like SLF4J, Log4J, java.util.logging, etc.?

**Edit:** Thanks to your answers, this would be the recommendation so far:

- If I can avoid to write a custom logger, perfect. If I have a good reason to do it, I will hope that no one will kill me.
- There are a lot of features that I would miss when the application be pushed live.
- So far, the [Chain-of-responsibility pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) looks like a good idea to implement in short time and give me more control over the output.
- Anyway, I'm going to check again the code just in case I miss something and I can make it work with a well-known log library. It's worth trying.

Comment: *Is it a bad idea to write an own logger?* Not necessarily. When your reasons are sensible, it is not. Also, it is a good exercise. *[...] what features I will miss [...]?* You are definitely missing some kind of timestamp. Also, I would recommend to take a look at the [Chain of Responsibility Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern). You might want to desing your logger around this, giving you the possibility to write different Levels to different loggers.

Comment: Why would it be a bad idea to write your own logger if the other log libraries don't meet your needs? But to be honest. This is not a logger? This is a wrapper class around system.out.

Comment: Hi @jjtbsomhorst  What would make it a real logger and not just a simple wrapper? Or are you trying to say that every logger, in deep, are just wrappers?

Comment: can you explain what problems you had with the other loggers in more detail, and also what problem you solved with this (your own) logger?
(PS: i agree with the others)

Comment: They were very annoying issues. For example, if I used Log4J or SLF4J (I dont' remember), there was a conflict with the version installed with Lotus Domino. If I tried to use the other one, it raised a new conflict with other version imported for jcifs? tika? (I don't remember too). If I tried to use java.util.logging, it worked well, until I had to manipulate the handlers. New conflict...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had have lot of compatibility problems between the log libraries like SLF4J, Log4J, java.util.logging, etc. and Lotus Notes.

Without knowing what those issues were, it is difficult to advise you.  There may have been a simple fix or work-around.

> Is it a bad idea to write a logger?

Reinventing the wheel is a bad idea.  Unless you really *need* a different kind of wheel.

> Do I have to insist in make it works one of the existent log libraries?

Your choice.

> If I decide to use always this logger, what features I will miss from the log libraries like SLF4J, Log4J, java.util.logging, etc.?

Hard to say what you will miss, because it depends on what you need.

However, some of the things that are missing from your attempted solution include:

- Logging to multiple files, file rotation, etcetera.
- Logging to a variety of kinds of event handling systems.
- Coarse / fine-grain configurability of logging ... without changing code.
- Compatibility; e.g. if you need to integrate with 3rd party software that uses a standard logging framework.

And then there is the revulsion that other Java programmers are liable to express if they need to maintain your code.

Comment: _"Without knowing what those issues were"_   Well, they were very annoying issues. For example, if I used Log4J or SLF4J (I dont' remember), there was a conflict with the version installed with Lotus Domino. If I tried to use java.util.logging, it worked well, until I had to manipulate the handlers. New conflict. I learned not to waste time on issues like those. That's the reason why I did it. I guess that I have to write a very good comment explaining why the custom logger, to avoid revulsions from other Java developers...

Comment: It sound like those issues could (easily) have been addressed.  And a good comment won't help ... :-)

Comment: It could be... I'm new one in the (Java) neighborhood. I agree with you about that reinventing the wheel is a bad idea. I'm going to check again the code. Maybe I miss something.

Answer (score 1):

Why would it be a bad idea to write your own logger if the other log libraries don't meet your needs? But to be honest. This is a log class around system.out.println(). I would hardly call that a logger.

The problem with this is that I will be very hard for an admin / you to troubleshoot this. Now all messages will be placed in the log.nsf and for that when you are debugging your log will be unclear and hard to read.

Please take a look at openlog project and add your own wrapper around it to make it work as you want it (if needed). This way you can have your own log database (or log in the same database? ) which will be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: You''re right about it's bad practice to place the entries in the log.nsf. As I'm  using a development server, it's not important, but it will be when I push live the application. About OpenLog, I worked with it some time ago, but I don't remember why I left to use it... I will try again.

Comment: XPages OpenLog Logger is specifically coded to add that wrapper around the core OpenLog Java. It also catches uncaught exceptions in SSJS / EL code, as well as providing a managed bean specifically for SSJS logging. It also, by default, returns the error to the browser. In addition there are a host of XSP properties available to configure various elements.

Answer (score 1):

Well I haven't worked extensively with loggers but one thing which comes to my mind is that with log libraries you have certain configuration which comes really handy.

For example - you can set the size of your log file, suppose 200 MB, as soon as file reaches 200MB it will create a new log file and on top of that you can set a maximum limit for example 10 GB or 10 backup files, Hence if all the log files reaches 10GB it would start deleting oldest file.

Also some log libraries provides different log level applied on different packages. That's really useful specially in development.

If you can handle those on your own I don't see much problem in using custom loggers.